# VSCODE : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, visual-studio-code, classnotfoundexception

I am getting classpath not found exception in vscode and spring mvc. I tried all the solutions available on SO, None of them worked.

```
[Tomcat 8.5]: Jun 10, 2020 11:09:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\48112ea668fdb8e04368dd8a69e48b1e\adashen.vscode-tomcat\tomcat\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\cheruvu-spring]
[Tomcat 8.5]: Jun 10, 2020 11:09:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
[Tomcat 8.5]: Jun 10, 2020 11:09:50 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[Tomcat 8.5]: Jun 10, 2020 11:09:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [dispatcher] as unavailable
[Tomcat 8.5]: Jun 10, 2020 11:09:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/cheruvu-spring] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:545)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[Tomcat 8.5]: Jun 10, 2020 11:09:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\48112ea668fdb8e04368dd8a69e48b1e\adashen.vscode-tomcat\tomcat\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\cheruvu-spring] has finished in [121] ms
```

Adding my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cheruvu-spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>cheruvu-spring</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cheruvu Maven Webapp</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.6.2</jackson.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.2.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <filter.name>DEV</filter.name>
        <jersey.version>1.9</jersey.version>
        <base.directory>${basedir}</base.directory>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <filter.name>DEV</filter.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <filter.name>DEV</filter.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>prod</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <filter.name>PROD</filter.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kencochrane.raven</groupId>
            <artifactId>raven-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.spullara.mustache.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.354</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flipkart.zjsonpatch</groupId>
            <artifactId>zjsonpatch</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.354</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- <filters> <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/ENV-${filter.name}/application.properties</filter> 
            </filters> -->
        <finalName>cheruvu-spring</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <debuglevel>source,lines</debuglevel>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <environment>prod</environment>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>revision</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <entries>
                            <entry>
                                <prefix>svn</prefix>
                            </entry>
                        </entries>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-timestamp</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>create-timestamp</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}</format>
                        <items>
                            <item>timestamp</item>
                        </items>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are missing e dependency `spring-webmvc` to be precise. So I doubt you have tried **all** the solutions.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have that dependency, let me add my pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Although it is in your list of dependencies it either isn't in your war (are you building one?) or the dependency is borked. I suspect the first one and that you aren't properly using the maven integration in VSCode (not knowing about the dependencies). To make sure to not have a borked jar, run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to remove the dependencies and re-download them on the next build.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the response, I found a workaround and posted it as my answer. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this. VSCode have generated .war file for the project, I have manually copied the file to webapp directory of tomcat server and started the server again. Tomcat have successfully loaded the webapp and API started working, I don't know if there was dependency issue or not, But this solution worked for me.